# LIGHTNING LND failed to load config: lnd.conf: unknown option: logdir?

Tags: lightning-network, lightning-network-daemon, logging

In my lnd.conf:

```
logdir=Z:\LND\logs
```

logdir is a valid option according to:
[sample-lnd.conf](https://github.com/lightningnetwork/lnd/blob/master/sample-lnd.conf)

but I get:

```
Z:\LND> .\lnd --configfile=Z:\LND\lnd.conf
failed to load config: Z:\LND\lnd.conf:55: unknown option: logdir
```

I am running LND ***lnd-windows-amd64-v0.14.2-beta*** on Windows 10.
I get this error w/ other valid .conf options too.

When I comment out the offending option, LND launches as expected:

```
Z:\LND> .\lnd --configfile=Z:\LND\lnd.conf
2022-03-16 09:28:54.763 [INF] LTND: Version: 0.14.2-beta commit=v0.14.2-beta, build=production, logging=default, debuglevel=info
2022-03-16 09:28:54.763 [INF] LTND: Active chain: Bitcoin (network=testnet)
2022-03-16 09:28:54.763 [INF] RPCS: RPC server listening on 127.0.0.1:10009
2022-03-16 09:28:54.763 [INF] RPCS: gRPC proxy started at 127.0.0.1:8080
2022-03-16 09:28:54.763 [INF] LTND: Opening the main database, this might take a few minutes...
2022-03-16 09:28:54.773 [INF] LTND: Opening bbolt database, sync_freelist=false, auto_compact=false
2022-03-16 09:28:54.773 [INF] LTND: Creating local graph and channel state DB instances
2022-03-16 09:28:54.783 [INF] CHDB: Checking for schema update: latest_version=24, db_version=24
2022-03-16 09:28:54.783 [INF] LTND: Database(s) now open (time_to_open=10.384ms)!
2022-03-16 09:28:54.783 [INF] LTND: We're not running within systemd
2022-03-16 09:28:54.783 [INF] LTND: Waiting for wallet encryption password. Use `lncli create` to create a wallet, `lncli unlock` to unlock an existing wallet, or `lncli changepassword` to change the password of an existing wallet and unlock it.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .conf file needs the section annotations.
As soon as I added:

```
[Application Options]
logdir=Z:\LND\logs
```

just above the logdir option everything works accordingly & the logdir is created as expected.